Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как смотреть изображение экрана opencv
подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи opencv смотреть изображение экрана, например
здесь cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) смотрит с камеры компьютера,
здесь video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.134:4747/video") с веб камеры,
здесь output = "C:/Users/Root/Desktop/video.avi" наверное должен смотреть с экрана
здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...reen-in-python куча всяких вариантов, но из за того что пользователям нужно записать изображение они используют pyautogui или screenhot поэтому код получается длинным, а мне нужно просто обратить око opencv на экран монитора моего монитора
